# How do I install numpy on windows python 3.4?

Tags: python, numpy

I have Python 3.4.3 on windows 8.1. I downloaded numpy to my downloads folder, unzipped it to downloads/numpy-1.9.1
and copied it to python34/lib and renamed it to numpy

Comment: Why don't you use `pip`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows

Comment: Numpy binaries for windows are [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).

Answer (score -1):

Try pip. It can be installed with

```
easy_install pip
```

if you don't have it already. Then, it's just a matter of

```
pip install numpy
```

Comment: Why would adding "sudo before it and type in your password" helped on windows 8.1? Even if, I doubt it will work as installing numpy requires lots of compiling.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't know that sudo won't work on windows. I'll edit the post.

Comment: This almost certainly won't work.  Installing numpy via pip requires a working toolchain in order to build the C extensions, which is far from trivial to set up on Windows.